# SQL Pivot with Dynamic Dates

Tags: sql

I'm attempting to build a report that sums up total sales by item by week for the past 4 weeks.  For example:

```
|-Item-|-1Week-|-2Weeks-|-3Weeks-|-4Weeks-|
|-Pens-|---100-|---1000-|----800-|------0-|
|Pencil|-----0-|----600-|---1500-|---2000-|
```

The following query returns precisely what I expect for the previous week, however, I've run into a roadblock when it comes to changing the query to sum each of the previous 4 weeks separately.

```
SELECT        itemmast.itemcode, itemmast.description, itemmast.packsize, SUM(sodetail.order_quantity) AS qtyweek1
FROM            dbo.soheader AS soheader INNER JOIN
                         dbo.sodetail AS sodetail ON soheader.invoice_number = sodetail.invoice_number INNER JOIN
                         dbo.itemmast AS itemmast ON sodetail.itemcode = itemmast.itemcode
WHERE        (soheader.so_issue_datetime > DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 0)) AND (soheader.so_issue_datetime < DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
GROUP BY itemmast.itemcode, itemmast.description, itemmast.packsize, sodetail.order_uomid
```

I get the basics of a pivot table (never had to use one as I'm pretty new to SQL) but I'm unsure of how to turn dynamic date ranges into columns and accomplish my goal.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue by adding the example below to the select statement for each week I need and simply adjusting the DATEDIFF arguments.

```
isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN (soheader.so_issue_datetime > DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 0)) AND (soheader.so_issue_datetime < DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) THEN sodetail.order_quantity END),0) AS "1 Week"
```